# Java applet can't find printers (granted permission) on CentOS 6 with CUPS

Tags: java

PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() returns null in the applet but returns the default printer when called in a small application.

I tried permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "queuePrintJob" and also clicking OK to grant permission to the applet to access the printer. The applet also has permission for port 631. I thought it might be a CUPS problem but the application works.

PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null) returns an empty list.

This is for a kiosk so I can set whatever permissions are required.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it by adding the following line in GRANT section of java.policy file:

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

Although giving all permissions is not recommended but couldn't file any other solution. Please post if anyone got the exact solution.

Thanks.